# Unmet dependencies while installing php5-curl

Tags: 14.04, apt, php, dependencies, curl

I am trying to install php5-curl via terminal in Ubuntu 14.04. 
I got following error.

```
sanchit@sanchit-Satellite-A660:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then did `sudo apt-get upgrade`. And I am getting the same error.

```
sanchit@sanchit-Satellite-A660:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
sanchit@sanchit-Satellite-A660:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

At some places it is advised to use Synaptic, but I am keen on solving it using terminal.

Comment: Your system isn't getting the current versions of either php5-curl or php5-common from your software sources indicating that you either haven't updated your software sources recently by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or else there is a package conflict caused by a PPA. Are there any PPAs in your software sources?

Comment: There are PPA for android-studio and java.
`sudo apt-get update` didn't help either.